# CSS inherit alpha color

Tags: html, css, colors, alpha

i want to do the following thing with inline styles:

```html
<div style="color: #00FC0056;">
  <h1 style="color: rgba(255, 0, 0, inherit);">Hello, world!</h1>
</div>
```

I want the alpha value of the color to be inherit.

Is it possible, and if so how can I do this?

Comment: But opacity changes the opacity of the whole container and its children right? so it does not only effect the text, but the entire elements. I only want to effect the text.

Comment: Why can't you do this in a seperate stylesheet?? Is there a reason for that?

Comment: I can do it in a seperate style sheet. I can generate a style tag with a unique class name and add the class name to the text container. However, the problem is the same. There is no rgba(r,g,b,inherit) in css

Comment: @Horst did you see my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS vars

```html
<div style="--alpha:.56">
    <h1 style="color: rgba(255,0,0, var(--alpha))">Hello, world!</h1>
</div>
```